# Pointwise Kan extensions VS weighted limits

Tags: ct.category-theory, limits-and-colimits, kan-extension

$\newcommand{\Dist}{\operatorname{Dist}} \newcommand{\Ran}{\operatorname{Ran}} \newcommand{\Lim}{\operatorname{Lim}}$

---

TLDR

Given a pointwise kan extension, how can we go from

$$ \Dist(B, C)(\phi_c \otimes V, \phi_{\Ran_g f} ) \simeq \Dist(A,C)(\phi_c\otimes V \otimes \phi_g, \phi_f)$$

(naturally in $c : 1 \to C$ and $V : 1 \nrightarrow C$) to
$$
 \Dist(B,C)(H,\phi_{\Lim^Jf}) \simeq \Dist(A,C) (H \otimes \phi_g, \phi_f)
$$

(naturally in $H : B \nrightarrow C$) using only distributor operation and density theorem.

---

notation :

- $\otimes$ for composition in distributors
- $\phi_f : A \nrightarrow B = B(-,f=)$ and $\phi^f : B \nrightarrow A = B(f-,=)$ the embeddings of a functor $f:A\to B$ in $\Dist$
- $[A,B]$ for the category of functors between $A$ and $B$
- $\Dist(A,B) = [B^\mathrm{op}\times A, \mathrm{Set}]$ for the category of distributors $A \nrightarrow B$

---

Detailed question :

It is clear that a weighted limit for $f:A\to C$  weighted by $\phi_g : A \nrightarrow B$ must be pointwise kan extension. The converse can be shown using a low-level construction, stated at [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kan+extension#PointwiseByWeightedColimits) as

> if a Kan extension  Lan p F  is pointwise, then one can prove that  (
> Lan p F ) ( c ′ )  must be in fact a  C ′ ( p ( − ) , c ′ )
> -weighted colimit of  F , and dually;

The statement is  straight forward as $(\Lim_PF)c = \Lim_{\phi^c\otimes P}F$ for any $c:X\to B$, and in particular for $c:1\to B$, for which the weighted limit reduces to an ordinary limit $\lim F\pi^c_g$. A *pointwise* kan extension evaluated at $c$ is also isomorphic to this limit. So the two functor are equal at each specific points.

This equality also determines the respective functor's action on arrow :
any arrow $b \to c$ in $B$ yields a cone from $\int \phi^{c}_g$, and by the UP of the limit at $c$, yields an arrow in the target category ending in the universal object $\lim f\pi^c_g$.

So this property of being equal to the limit at each specific point determines the functor $r$ and agreeing at each of those points yields the functor equality

$$\Ran_gf = \Lim_{\phi_g}f$$

---

But what is the high level analog proof of the previous low level construction ?

---

It seems mysterious to be able to go from the following UP to the next one, which is more general :

- A pointwise right kan extension $r$ of $f : A \to C $ along $g : A \to B$ has the following UPs natural in $x: B \to C$

$$[B, C](x, r)) \simeq [A,C](xg, f)$$

and the property, natural in $\bar{V} : B\to \mathrm{Set}$ and in $c : 1 \to C$

$$[B, \mathrm{Set}](\bar{V}, C(c,r-)) \simeq [A,\mathrm{Set}](\bar{V}g, C(c,f-))$$

which is equivalent to, naturally in $V : B \nrightarrow 1$ and $c : 1 \to C$

$$\Dist(B, 1)( V, \phi^c \otimes \phi_r ) \simeq \Dist(A,1)(V \otimes \phi_g, \phi^c\otimes \phi_f)$$

which is equivalent to, naturally in $V : B \nrightarrow 1$ and $c : 1 \to C$

$$\Dist(B, C)(\phi_c \otimes V, \phi_r ) \simeq \Dist(A,C)(\phi_c\otimes V \otimes \phi_g, \phi_f)$$

- The the UP of the weighted limit of a functor $f : A \to C $ along weights $\phi_g : A \nrightarrow B$ has UP, natural in $H$ (stating that its embedding is a right kan extension in $\Dist$)

$$
 \Dist(B,C)(H,\phi_{\Lim^Jf}) \simeq \Dist(A,C) (H \otimes \phi_g, \phi_f)
$$

---

The second UP seems more general as it applies to any $H : B \nrightarrow C$ and not just those of the form $\phi_c V : B \nrightarrow 1 \nrightarrow C $

Comment: I don't have time to give a proper answer now, but you may find it helpful to look at §8.1 of [The formal theory of relative monads](https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.14014v1), which describes explicitly why weighted colimits in the usual sense (e.g. of [Kelly](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/10/tr10.html)) are captured by right lifts in $\mathrm{Dist}$. (The case of weighted limits is dual.)

Comment: Thank you for the reference ! I will write up what I understood from the ref as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the equivalence becomes trivial if you add the hidden assumption, that is the hypothesis of representability of the extension in $Dist$

This is akin to Kelly's remark about limit in enriched settings  :

[image]

Comment: Glad you came back later to answer your own question!